# How to know whether app is opened for the first time after installing in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

As the question says how can I know that the app is launched for the first time in users device in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences` to know whether app opening first or second time onwards. This code should be at startup of you app like `OnCreate` of your `MainActivity`

```
var pref = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.Context);
var editorLogin = pref.Edit();

if (pref.GetBoolean("firstTime", true))
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "App opening first time", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    editorLogin.PutBoolean("firstTime", false).Commit();
}
else
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "App opening second time", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay I will try this one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I am aware of that you can use to do this the easy one would be the Shared preferences as they are available from the android side and are pretty lightweight.

The Xamarin.Android equivalent of `SharedPreferences` is an interface called `ISharedPreferences`.

For example, to save a true/false `bool` using some `Context` you can do the following:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();
editor.PutBoolean ("is_first_time", mBool);
// editor.Commit();    // applies changes synchronously on older APIs
editor.Apply();        // applies changes asynchronously on newer APIs
```

Access saved values using:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
mBool = prefs.GetBoolean ("is_first_time", <default value>);  
if(mBool)
{
 //this is first time   
 prefs.PutBoolean ("is_first_time", false).Apply();
}
else
{
//this is second time onwards
// your piece of code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, will try this.